# Javascript widget works fine on my own domain, but not on anyone elses?

Tags: javascript, json, widget

Created javascript widget. Testing on my own domain and its working fine. However when posting on a 3rd party site it looks like it's not connecting to the database and getting the data.

Here is the part of the js file where I get the data:

```
/******* Load HTML *******/
var jsonp_url = "http://www.example.com/widget/data.php";
$.getJSON(jsonp_url, function(data) {
```

When I test on example.com everything is fine. I set the permissions on data.php to 777 and it still isn't working. Please help!

Comment: http://www.mydomain.com/widget/data.php is a 404. Either that's the problem or you are using someone's real domain as your fake domain. Don't do that. example.com/net/org are [designed for that](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606#section-3)

Comment: When yoy say posting on a 3rd party site, you mean only the javascript widget or also de data.php file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a variable called `jsonp_url`, but the URL you use doesn't include the string `callback=?` which [the documentation says triggers jsonp mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp).

You need to include that in the URL and make sure that your server side script is outputting JSONP (using `$_GET['callback']` (with suitable sanitisation) to determine the function name you  wrap the JSON in).

Comment: I've gone ahead and added the call back:

var jsonp_url = "http://www.example.com/widget/data.php?callback=?";
$.getJSON(jsonp_url, function(data) {

But I'm not sure how to add it to the php file. Here is where I echo the json data:

   while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   
   $json = array(); 
  $json['coupon_name'] = $info['label'] ;
  $json['retailer_name'] = $info['name'] ;
  $json['logo_image'] = $info['logo_image'];
  $json['permalink'] = $info['permalink'];
  $data[] = $json;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);

Answer (score 2):

you cannot make an ajax call across different domains:
let's say your domain is 'example.com', and the third party site has 'thirdparty.com'.  you install the widget on thirdparty.com. The widget code on thirdparty.com will try to make an ajax request to 'example.com'. Which is forbidden by the browser.

You can always replace the ajax call with a straight < script > tag. This doesn't have any restriction.

Hope it helps

Comment: Is it because I'm missing a json callback?

Answer (score 0):

they need to enable cross orgin resource sharing. http://enable-cors.org/